# Pig isn't working in mapreduce mode

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

When I run the pig in local mode, it is running fine but in map reduce mode 
it is throwing error message

```
grunt> ls
```

> 2016-07-16 17:19:40,973 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt
>   - ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. File or directory null does not exist. Details at logfile: /home/hduser/pig_1468666911969.log

Please find the stack trace:

### Pig Stack Trace

> ERROR 2997: Encountered IOException. File or directory null does not
>   exist.
>
> java.io.IOException: File or directory null does not exist.   at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processLS(GruntParser.java:848)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScriptParser.java:485)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:230)
>     at
>   org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.java:205)
>     at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:66)  at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:565)    at
>   org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:177)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)    at
>   org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried `ls /`? Maybe it just needs a directory?

Comment: That helped i understood thanks @matthew Rathbone

Answer (score 0):

Either Your name node is not set up or Not started 
Format the name node and start again

Try to Run the command

```
hdfs dfs -ls
```